# When to use upper and lower half-circle when evaluating improper integrals (Residue Intergration)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

Im working on evaluating integrals of the form

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx$.

Im using the technique where i am looking at the corresponding complex function, $f(z)$, and integrating $f(z)$ over a contour formed as a semi-circle. Then i use the fact that the intergral is zero over the semi-cirlce to say that my improper integral is equal to the residues of $f(z)$ in my semi-cricle.

My question is simply, when should I use a semi-circle in the lower half-plane, and when should I use a semi-circle in the upper half plane to decide wich poles i should calculate the Residue of?

Comment: Whichever one "the intergral is zero over the semi-circle" is actually true for.

Comment: Often times, it is the case that both results in zero (e.g. $(\cosh(1)(iz-1)+e)\exp(iz)/(1+z^2)$). What one should look for instead is when it's easy to see this result through either the estimation lemma or Jordan's lemma or similar @eyeballfrog

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt In your example, the semicircle contour only vanishes for $Im(z)>0$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Wrong, as we have $0=\sum\operatorname{Res}$ (assuming I did it right)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt You seem to have misunderstood what I meant. It's the integral over the semicircle that has to go to zero, not the whole integral.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Ah sorry my last comment was unclear. I was saying the integral over an entire circle is zero, hence the semicircle over the upper half goes to 0 iff the semicircle over the lower half goes to 0.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Ah, I see. It is generally preferred that the semicircle contour go to zero *absolutely*. While the semicricle contour on the lower half of that function does happen to go to zero, it is only due to cancellations in the integral, and is not helpful for finding the integral over the real line.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I would rather not say that it must go to zero absolutely. Indeed I believe my example doesn't go to zero absolutely on either side. However, it goes to zero in the upper half by Jordan's lemma.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt It definitely goes to zero absolutely on the upper half plane. $\exp(iRe^{i\theta})$ decays exponentially with $R$ for $0 <\theta<\pi$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog It decays at different rates for different $\theta$, and does not decay for $\theta\in\{0,\pi\}$. Your argument would also imply that integrating $\exp(iz)/z$ over a square would go to 0 absolutely, but $\int_R^{R+iR}|\exp(iz)/z|~\mathrm dz$ most certainly does not go to zero as $R\to\infty$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I guess I don't get your point. If we call the function you posted $f(z)$, then $\int |f(z)|dz$ goes to zero on the upper semicircle but not the lower one. And also that integral *does* go to zero as $R\rightarrow \infty$, decaying as $1/R$. (We might want to take this to chat.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97261/discussion-between-simply-beautiful-art-and-eyeballfrog).

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt That $f$ is meromorphic with finitely many poles and that it vanishes at $\infty$ in every direction implies it is a rational function. The other case where we can use the residue theorem on both side is when $f$ has some essential singularities ($f(z) = \frac{1}{(z+i)^2\exp(1/(z+i))}$) and when it has infinitely many singularities of decreasing amplitude ($f(z) = \frac{1}{(z+i)^2 \cos(z+i)}$)